# Conectar com PostGreSQL

Tags: postgresql, firebird, ini

Possuo um arquivo `*.ini` que faz a conexão com meu banco de dados Firebird, porém preciso que agora esse arquivo seja configurado para conectar com o PostGreSQL

```
[IBConnection]
DriverName=Interbase          
Database=192.168.1.30:C:\testes\impressoes.fdb         
RoleName=RoleName         
User_Name=sysdba         
Password=masterkey        
ServerCharSet=             
SQLDialect=3               
ErrorResourceFile=        
LocaleCode=0000         
BlobSize=-1        
CommitRetain=False           
WaitOnLocks=True                     
Interbase TransIsolation=ReadCommited         
Trim Char=False
```

O que preciso, é descobrir o que é necessário alterar para conectar com o PostGreSQL ao invés do Firebird.

Dentro do código esta assim a conexão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conexão com Devart:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém sempre que tento acessar alguma tabela para verificar se a conexão está OK, vem a seguinte mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que ele encontrou meu DataBase certinho, porém não faço ideia de por que ele diz que tal tabela não existe

O erro que ele estava apresentando estava ocorrendo devido a tabela estar com o nome tudo em letra maiúscula, ao colocar em letra minúscula o erro não ocorreu novamente porém quando tento acessar alguma informação do banco ele esta acusando outro erro agora:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém esse FMTBcdField não é disponível como formato de varíavel, o que eu acredito que seja já que o erro compara com o formato Integer da variável.

Comment: Em alguma linguagem especifica?

Comment: @rray Na verdade, hoje em dia já existe uma aplicação que usa o firebird como banco de dados, eu não mexi na aplicação mas se não me engano a linguagem que foi usado foi Delph, eu vou editar a pergubnta e colocar tudo que esta no arquivo .ini pra tu ter uma ideia melhor

Comment: Acho q a mudança é que database e ip do servidor ficam em campos diferentes. Ainda assim está complicado de entender a perguntar

Comment: @rray Eu recriei todas as tabelas que existiam dentro deste arquivo `impressoes.fdb` no PostGreSQL, porém não sei como posso alterar a conexão para que ao invés de continuar salvando as informações dentro do banco firebird ele passe a salvar no postgreSQL

Comment: O que você deseja é que seu sistema deixei de se conectar no Firebird e se conecte ao PostgreSql ? Se for isso, pode ser que sua aplicação não funcione uma vez que ela usa um componente para acessar uma base do Firebird e não do PostgreSql.

Comment: Acredito que criar uma nova seção (`[PGConnection]`) com os campos, DriverName, User_Name, Password, DataBase (apenas o nome da base) e Host (ip do servidor) seja suficiente mas lembre que a aplicação deve ler esse padrão novo.

Comment: Faz sentido @JcSaint provavelmente dentro da aplicação ela esteja fazendo as alterações no banco. Vou precisar olhar a aplicação antes. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Vou tentar fazer essas alterações @rray se funcionar posto aqui.

Comment: @rray ali em DataBase que você disse apenas o nome da base, o que seria isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo, quando olhar a aplicação edite a pergunta com mais detalhes :)

Comment: @rray Consegui acessar o código fonte e alterei a pergunta pra mostrar onde esta a conexão (Não tenho total certeza se é ali ao certo que é determinada a conexão) mas a partir daquela imagem tu teria alguma ideia do que seria necessário para conectar ao PostGreSQL ao invés de ser ao FireBird?

Comment: Não sei dizer, tentaria procurar alguma coisa como 'conexão postgres via dbexpress'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo pela imagem que você postou seu aplicativo foi criado utilizando o Delphi 7 e ele não suportava nativamente conexão com PostgreSQL, porem existe drivers para o dbexpress que adicionam o suporte a conexão com PostgreSQL.

A devart possui drive para dbexpress, você pode verificar aqui https://www.devart.com/dbx/postgresql/

Encontre a versão especifica para Delphi 7, baixe, em seguida feche a IDE do Delphi e instale o drive, feito isso abra novamente e edite as configurações da conexão selecionando a opção nova que aparecera no Connection Name que provavelmente estará como PGSQLConnection, em seguida altere os parâmetros para os específicos do seu servidor PostgreSQL.

Comment: editei a pergunta para mostrar como ficou a janela de configuração do dbExpress com o devart, Seria isso que você estava querendo dizer?

Comment: Tem algum motivo pras informações estarem todas incompletas, e outras ele ta trazendo até (Memo) ao invés dos dados

Comment: R.Santos o que esta acontecendo é que os tipos de dados mapeados pelo drive do postgresql são diferentes dos que estão mapeados nos datasets pelo drive do firebird. Nessa ultima mensagem de erro ele esta dizendo exatamente isso que ele estava esperando que o campo código no dataset fosse do tipo FMTBCDField porem esta mapeado no dataset como integer.

Comment: Nas versões mais novas do drive da devart existe configurações de mapeamento dos tipos e você consegue definir por exemplo que um campo númerico da sua base de dados ex. numeric(15,0) seja mapeado para inteiro invés de float que é o padrão que ele esta mapeando. De uma olhada neste link da devart http://blog.devart.com/data-type-mapping-in-delphi-data-access-components.html

Comment: Obrigado por toda a ajuda @Diego Garcia, tu sabe dizer se é apenas pago o devart?

Comment: R. Santos pelo que sei é pago apenas sim. Mas eu não acho que é tão caro pelo que ele se propõem fora que a performance dos drives deles são muito superiores as nativas do delphi nas versões antigas antes do firedac.

Comment: Vale lembrar também que para resolver esse problema que você teve dos tipos de uma forma um pouco mais trabalhosa e sem o mapeamento é possível também basta você achar o dataset que deu problema (clientdataset, query, sqldataset), clicar com o botão direito nele, selecionar a opção FieldDefs, remover o campo problemático e adicionar novamente clicando com o botão direito e selecionando a opção add fields. Com isso o campo sera recriado porem com o formato novo.

Comment: Eu sei que não tem a ver com o tópico, mas tu sabe me dizer se é possível e como se faz para adicionar uma conexão com o postgreSQL via ODBC no Delphi 7? É que é meio caro o Devart para adquirir, e via ODBC também resolveria meu problema

Comment: Ali onde você diz em resolver o meu problema com os tipo, está se referindo ao formato dos campos no banco?

Comment: R. Santos, na verdade estava falando em resolver o segundo problema que vc teve após ter colocado o drive da devart, para não ter que configurar o mapeamento.

Comment: Para usar o ODBC você precisa usar o ADOConnection e não o dbexpress, por ele basta configurar o connection string e usar, mas acho que você terá mais trabalho dessa forma.